# Java multiple regular expression search

Tags: java, regex

I have a string some thing like this:

```
If message contains sensitive info like: {Password:123456, tmpPwd : tesgjadgj, TEMP_PASSWORD: kfnda}
```

My pattern should look for the particular words `Password` or `tmpPwd` or `TEMP_PASSWORD`.

How can I create a pattern for this kind of search?

Comment: `(Password|tmpPwd|TEMP_PASSWORD)`

Comment: Thank you Karthik. I am looking for this solution only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am using it like as per my requirement .

> private final static String censoredWords =
>   "(?i)PASSWORD|pwd";

The `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive

Comment: Thank you !     This answer is useful to me

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the values after these words. You need to set capturing groups to extract those values, e.g.

```
String content = "If message contains sensitive info like: {Password:123456, tmpPwd : tesgjadgj, TEMP_PASSWORD: kfnda} ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{Password\\s*:\\s*([^,]+)\\s*,\\s*tmpPwd\\s*:\\s*([^,]+)\\s*,\\s*TEMP_PASSWORD:\\s*([^,]+)\\s*\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ", " + m.group(3));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8epZHu)

This will output `123456, tesgjadgj, kfnda`.

To just find out if there are any of the substrings, use `contains` method:

```
System.out.println(content.contains("Password") || 
                       content.contains("tmpPwd") ||
                       content.contains("TEMP_PASSWORD"));
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/12RNr5)

And if you want a regex-solution for the keywords, here it is:

```
String str = "If message contains sensitive info like: {Password:123456, tmpPwd : tesgjadgj, TEMP_PASSWORD: kfnda} ";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("Password|tmpPwd|TEMP_PASSWORD");
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Match found: " + m.group(0));
}
```

See [Demo 3](https://ideone.com/0Pctj9)

Comment: Thank you I am looking for keywords

Comment: But then you do not need a regex, just `contains` is enough. I added another snippet showing how it can be done without regex. Surely, you can use alternation in regex, but unless you need to check for *whole words*, the `contains` method is sufficient.

Comment: Yes , What you said is correct , contains will be fine , but I thought using regex will be more efficient than usual string comparison, creating array of words looping them and searching for them in the msg. I am trying to use this code masking message at logging. If the message contains above sensitive words I will not log the message . I tried to look into log4j config but I couldnt find any , so thought of using regex

Comment: Ok, I see, but in 99.9% of cases when you do not have to use a regex, you should not use regex, as it is slowing down your application much more than using string functions.

Comment: Thank you . Finally I am using it like as  per my requirement . 
  private final static String censoredWords = "PASSWORD|Password|password|Pwd|pwd|PWD";
But is there anyway to update my pattern , to avoid writing words in all cases

Comment: You should use an ignore case flag with the pattern: `Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:Password|tmpPwd|TEMP_PASSWORD)");`